# running cmd in c# answer yes to prompt

Tags: c#

I'm running the below command from c#.  There is a prompt that will be shown that I want to answer "yes" to how can I do this with the current code

If I run this as a batch script I can just do

```
echo y | pscp.exe -batch -pw password E:\\Certs\\client.conf me@<ip>:/home/user
```

which works - but unsure how I can replicate this using the below

```
string pscpPath="-batch -pw password E:\\Certs\\client.conf me@<ip>:/home/user";

ExecuteCopyCerts("pscp.exe", pscpPath);
```

Function:

```
public Boolean ExecuteCopyCerts(string fileName, string arguments)
{
    txtLiveHubStatus.Text = "";

    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(fileName, arguments);
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        return proc.ExitCode == 0;         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `RedirectStandardInput` to `true`

```
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true
```

and then write to `StandardInput`

```
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate what Hesam said though the prompt is Y, not yes.   This is the prompt for the cert, which only occurs on the first call to each new linux machine.  I use this code today in one of our applications.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "pscp";
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
psi.Arguments = $"-r -p -pw {passWord} \"{localFileNamePath}\" {userName}@{hostName}:{remotePath}";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo = psi;
    process.Start();
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y");
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```